# Both AssertEqual and AssertNotEqual give failure in my unittest in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, python-unittest, assert

I have this test code on Binary Tree:

```
def test_deleteMin_root(self):
    btree = BinaryTree()
    min_value = self.person('AAKVIK', 'ANNE-MARIT', 'RISØYVEGEN 17', '1705', 'SARPSBORG')
    node = BinaryTreeNode(min_value)
    btree.insert(value = min_value)
    btree.insert(value = self.person('Zero', 'Zero', 'Zero street', '1234', 'ZeroCity'))
    btree.deleteMin()
    self.assertEqual(node, btree.findMin())
```

I get this failure result:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_deleteMin_root (__main__.BinaryTreeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdka\Documents\Programs\Python\PythonExercises\aicourse\test_binarytree.py", line 47, in test_deleteMin_root
    self.assertEqual(node, btree.findMin())
AssertionError: <BinaryTreeNode.BinaryTreeNode object at 0x000001C7E33EFA00> != <BinaryTreeNode.BinaryTreeNode object at 0x000001C7EAB5A6D0>
```

When I change AssertEqual to AssertNotEqual in the last line of the test code (and that's the only thing I change):

```
def test_deleteMin_root(self):
    btree = BinaryTree()
    min_value = self.person('AAKVIK', 'ANNE-MARIT', 'RISØYVEGEN 17', '1705', 'SARPSBORG')
    node = BinaryTreeNode(min_value)
    btree.insert(value = min_value)
    btree.insert(value = self.person('Zero', 'Zero', 'Zero street', '1234', 'ZeroCity'))
    btree.deleteMin()
    self.assertNotEqual(node, btree.findMin())
```

I get this failure:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_deleteMin_root (__main__.BinaryTreeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdka\Documents\Programs\Python\PythonExercises\aicourse\test_binarytree.py", line 47, in test_deleteMin_root
    self.assertNotEqual(node, btree.findMin())
AssertionError: <BinaryTreeNode.BinaryTreeNode object at 0x000001C7EE3D4F10> == <BinaryTreeNode.BinaryTreeNode object at 0x000001C7E5DCAA00>
```

**When I assert equal, it says they're not equal, and when I assert not equal, it says they're equal. I don't understand; what's the error here?  How can I fix it?**

Here's the full test code, BinaryTree code and BinaryTreeNode code:

Binary Tree code:

```
from BinaryTreeNode import BinaryTreeNode

class BinaryTree:    
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self._root = None
        if isinstance(data, BinaryTreeNode):
            self._root = data

    def findLeftMost(self, treenode):
        left = treenode.left
        if left == None:
            return treenode
        return self.findLeftMost(left)
    
    def findMin(self):
        return self.findLeftMost(self._root)
        
    def findRightMost(self, treenode):
        right = treenode.right
        if right == None:
            return treenode
        return self.findRightMost(right)
    
    def findMax(self):
        return self.findRightMost(self._root)
    
    def find(self, key, treenode = None):
        if treenode == None:
            treenode = self._root
        if treenode == None:
            return None
        elif treenode.value > key:
            if treenode.left:
                return self.find(key, treenode.left)
        elif treenode.value < key:
            if treenode.right:
                return self.find(key, treenode.right)
        elif treenode.value == key:
            return treenode
        else:
            raise KeyError("Key not found")
       
    def _getnodes(self, current = None, treenode = None, value = None):
        if current != None and treenode != None:
            return current, treenode
        if value == None:
            if treenode == None:
                raise Exception("Attempt to insert an empty space into Binary Tree")
            else:
                if treenode.value == None:
                    raise Exception("Attempt to insert an Node into Binary Tree with no key value")
        else:
            if treenode != None:
                if treenode.value != None:
                    raise Exception("Key inconsistency detected")
            else:
                treenode = BinaryTreeNode(value)
        if current == None:
            current = self._root
        return current, treenode
    
    def insert(self, current = None, treenode = None, value = None):
        if current == None:
            current = self._root
        # Checking consistency ...
        current, treenode = self._getnodes(current, treenode, value)
        if current != None:
            if treenode.value < current.value:
                treenode.level += 1
                if current.left is None:
                    current.left = treenode
                else:
                    self.insert(current.left, treenode)
            elif treenode.value > current.value:
                treenode.level += 1
                if current.right is None:
                    current.right = treenode
                else:
                    self.insert(current.right, treenode)
            else:
                if self._root == None:
                    treenode.level = 0
                    self._root = treenode
                else:
                    raise Exception("Duplicate key: " + treenode.value)
        else: # If empty tree, the first node entered is the root
            self._root = treenode
        return treenode

    def deleteMin(self):
        parent = self._root
        while True:
            # If a left branch exists - find the smallest item
            current = parent.left
            if current:
                if current.left == None:
                    if current.right != None:
                        parent.left = current.right
                        return current
                    else:
                        parent.left = None
                        return current                  
                else:
                    parent = current
            # If no left branch exists, the root item is the smallest in the tree
            else:
                self._root = parent.right
                return self._root
    
    def deleteMax(self):
        parent = self._root            
        while True:
            current = parent.right
            if current.right == None:
                if current.left != None:
                    parent.right = current.left
                    return current
                else:
                    parent.right = None
                    return current                   
            else:
                parent = current
        
    def delete(self, key):
        node = self.find(key)
        delnode = node
        if not node.left and not node.right:
            node = None
        elif node.right:
            temptree = BinaryTree(node.right)
            mintempnode = temptree.deleteMin()
            node.value = mintempnode.value
        elif node.left:
            node = node.left  
        return delnode
```

Binary Tree Node code:

```
class BinaryTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value, 
                 lefttree = None, 
                 righttree = None):
        self.value = value      
        self.left = lefttree
        self.right = righttree
        self.level = 0

    # Bruker setter/getters
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self.__value = value
    
    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.__left 
    
    @left.setter
    def left(self, lefttree):
        self.__left = lefttree 
   
    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.__right        
    
    @right.setter
    def right(self, righttree):
        self.__right = righttree 

    @property
    def level(self):
        return self.__level
    
    @level.setter
    def level(self, level):
        self.__level = level
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
    
    def hasRight(self):
        if self.right == None:
            return False
        return True
        #return self.right != None            
    
    def hasLeft(self):
        if self.left == None:
            return False
        return True
        #return self.left != None
    
    def prefixOrder(self):
        print(str(self.value), ' ')
        if self.hasLeft():
            self.left.prefixOrder()
        if self.hasRight():
            self.right.prefixOrder()
        
    def infixOrder(self):
        if self.hasLeft():
            self.left.infixOrder()
        print(str(self.value), ' ')
        if self.hasRight():
            self.right.infixOrder()
        
    def postfixOrder(self):
        if self.hasLeft():
            self.left.postfixOrder()
        if self.hasRight():
            self.right.postfixOrder()
        print(str(self.value), ' ')
        
    def levelOrder(self):
        from queue import SimpleQueue
        FIFOQueue = SimpleQueue()
        FIFOQueue.put(self)
        self.levelOrderEntry(FIFOQueue)
        while not FIFOQueue.empty():
            node = FIFOQueue.get()
            print(str(node.value), ' ')
                
    def levelOrderEntry(self, queue):
        if queue.empty():
            return
        node = queue.get()
        print(str(node.value), ' ')
        if node.hasLeft():
            queue.put(node.left)
        if node.hasRight():
            queue.put(node.right)
        if node.hasLeft() or node.hasRight:
            self.levelOrderEntry(queue)            

    def __eq__(self, other):   
        if other != None:
            return self.value == other.value
        elif other == None and self.value == None:
            return True
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if other != None:
            if self.value == None:
                return False
            else:
                return not self.value != other.value
        return True
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other != None:
            return self.value < other.value
        elif other == None and self.value == None:
            return False
        return False
    
    def __le__(self, other):
        if other != None:
            return self.value <= other.value
        elif other == None and self.value == None:
            return False
        return False
               
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if other != None:
            return self.value > other.value
        elif other == None and self.value == None:
            return False
        return False
    
    def __ge__(self, other):
        if other != None:
            return self.value >= other.value
        elif other == None and self.value == None:
            return False
        return False
```

The full test code:

```
import unittest
from BinaryTree import BinaryTree
from BinaryTreeNode import BinaryTreeNode
from collections import namedtuple

class BinaryTreeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.person = namedtuple('person', ['lastname', 'firstname', 'address',
                                            'postalcode', 'city'])
        persons_file = open("Personer-kort.dta", 'r')
        content = persons_file.read()
        content = content.splitlines()
        self.binarytree = BinaryTree()   
        for p in content:
            self.binarytree.insert(value = self.person(*p.split(';')))
        persons_file.close()
    
        
    def test_findMin(self):
        min_value = self.person('AAKVIK', 'ANETTE', 'BAKLIEN 11', '1360', 'NESBRU')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(min_value)
        self.assertEqual(node, self.binarytree.findMin())
    
    def test_findMax(self):
        max_value = self.person('ØYFOSS', 'ØISTEIN', 'ORHEIM 76', '0367', 'OSLO')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(max_value)
        self.assertEqual(node, self.binarytree.findMax())
        
    def test_deleteMin(self):
        self.binarytree.deleteMin()
        min_value = self.person('AAKVIK', 'ANNE-MARIT', 'RISØYVEGEN 17', '1705', 'SARPSBORG')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(min_value)
        self.assertEqual(node, self.binarytree.findMin())

    def test_deleteMin_root(self):
        btree = BinaryTree()
        min_value = self.person('AAKVIK', 'ANNE-MARIT', 'RISØYVEGEN 17', '1705', 'SARPSBORG')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(min_value)
        btree.insert(value = min_value)
        btree.insert(value = self.person('Zero', 'Zero', 'Zero street', '1234', 'ZeroCity'))
        btree.deleteMin()
        self.assertNotEqual(node, btree.findMin())
    
    def test_deleteMax(self):
        self.binarytree.deleteMax()
        max_value = self.person('ØYFOSS', 'WERNER STENVOLD', 'KIRKVOLL 28', '5935', 'LAVIK')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(max_value)
        self.assertEqual(node, self.binarytree.findMax())
        
    
    def test_find(self):
        value = self.person('SKARSHAUG','ASBJØRN HARALD', 'ALAPMO 72', '7290', 'STØREN')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(value)
        self.assertEqual(node, self.binarytree.find(value))
    
    def test_find_key_not_found(self):
        value = self.person('BORIS','JOHNSON', 'SOME STREET 72', '1234', 'LONDON')
        self.assertEqual(None, self.binarytree.find(value))
        self.assertRaises(KeyError, self.binarytree.find, value)


    def test_delete(self):
        value = self.person('SKARSHAUG','ASBJØRN HARALD', 'ALAPMO 72', '7290', 'STØREN')
        node = BinaryTreeNode(value)
        self.assertEqual(node, self.binarytree.find(value))
        self.binarytree.delete(value)
        self.assertEqual(None, self.binarytree.find(value))
        
    
    def test_insert_value(self):
        value1 = self.person('WIKILUND','JOHAN', 'SVETUN 11', '8510', 'NARVIK')
        node1 = BinaryTreeNode(value1)
        value2 = self.person('ALFRED', 'POLLEN', 'gate 11', '1234', 'KONGSBERG')
        node2 = BinaryTreeNode(value2)
        self.binarytree.insert(value=value1)
        self.binarytree.insert(value=value2)
        self.assertEqual(node1, self.binarytree.find(value1))
        self.assertEqual(node2, self.binarytree.find(value2))
    
    def test_insert_node(self):
        value1 = self.person('WIKILUND','JOHAN', 'SVETUN 11', '8510', 'NARVIK')
        node1 = BinaryTreeNode(value1)
        value2 = self.person('ALFRED', 'POLLEN', 'gate 11', '1234', 'KONGSBERG')
        node2 = BinaryTreeNode(value2)
        self.binarytree.insert(treenode=node1)
        self.binarytree.insert(treenode=node2)
        self.assertEqual(node1, self.binarytree.find(value1))
        self.assertEqual(node2, self.binarytree.find(value2))
    
    def test_insert_duplicate(self):
        value = self.person('SKARSHAUG','ASBJØRN HARALD', 'ALAPMO 72', '7290', 'STØREN')
        self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, "Duplicate key", self.binarytree.insert, [None, None, value])
    
    def test_insert_empty_space(self):
        self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, "Attempt to insert an empty space into Binary Tree",
                                self.binarytree.insert, [None, None, None])
    
    def test_insert_empty_node(self):
        node = BinaryTreeNode(None)
        self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, "Attempt to insert an Node into Binary Tree with no key value",
                        self.binarytree.insert, [None, node, None])
    
    def test_find_in_empty_tree(self):
        tree = BinaryTree()
        value = self.person('SKARSHAUG','ASBJØRN HARALD', 'ALAPMO 72', '7290', 'STØREN')
        self.assertEqual(None, tree.find(value))
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'BinaryTreeTest']
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your `BinaryTreeNode` class overrides both `__eq__` and `__ne__` independently. If they both return false, then your objects will neither be equal (`==`) nor nonequal (`!=`).

Comment: In particular, this line `return not self.value != other.value` is a double negative, and probably isn't what you need there.